# making a method checking if the values in a dataframe are a particular value

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, dataframe

I am making a tic tac toe game using a dataframe. How could i make a function to check if there are three in a row of type 'o' or 'x' and make it change the game status to DONE. I have so far made it so that the user can append the slots by putting in coordinates and the character they choose to fill it with.

```
import pandas as pd

tic_tac_toe = { 'col1' : ('-','-','-'), 'col2': ('-','-','-'),'col3': ('-','-','-')}
dataframetictac = pd.DataFrame(data = tic_tac_toe)
dftt= dataframetictac.rename(index={0: 'row1', 1: 'row2', 2 : 'row3'})
game_status = "NOT OVER"

while game_status != "DONE":

    user_move = input("Enter row number,column number, either x or an o :\n for example %%!(1,1,x)")
    if user_move == '(1,1,x)':
        dftt.at['row1','col1'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(1,1,o)':
        dftt.at['row1','col1'] = 'O'
    if user_move == '(2,1,x)':
        dftt.at['row2','col1'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(2,1,o)':
        dftt.at['row2','col1'] = 'O'
    if user_move == '(3,1,x)':
        dftt.at['row3','col1'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(3,1,o)':
        dftt.at['row3','col1'] = 'O'
    #
    if user_move == '(1,2,x)':
        dftt.at['row1','col2'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(1,2,o)':
        dftt.at['row1','col2'] = 'O'
    if user_move == '(2,2,x)':
        dftt.at['row2','col2'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(2,2,o)':
        dftt.at['row2','col2'] = 'O'
    if user_move == '(3,2,x)':
        dftt.at['row3','col2'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(3,2,o)':
        dftt.at['row3','col2'] = 'O'
    #
    if user_move == '(1,3,x)':
        dftt.at['row1','col3'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(1,3,o)':
        dftt.at['row1','col3'] = 'O'
    if user_move == '(2,3,x)':
        dftt.at['row2','col3'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(2,3,o)':
        dftt.at['row2','col3'] = 'O'
    if user_move == '(3,3,x)':
        dftt.at['row3','col3'] = 'X'
    if user_move == '(3,3,o)':
        dftt.at['row3','col3'] = 'O'
    print (dftt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code for "game over" function:

```
def columns_check(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if df.loc[df[col]=='x'].shape[0]==3 or df.loc[df[col]=='o'].shape[0]==3:
            return 'DONE'
    return 'The game is still on'
def rows_check(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row[row=='x'].shape[0]==3 or row[row=='o'].shape[0]==3:
            return 'DONE'
    return 'The game is still on'
def diagonal_check ():
    df_tmp=pd.DataFrame()
    for i, data in enumerate(dftt.iterrows()):
        index, row = data[0], data[1]
        df_tmp = df_tmp.append(row.shift(-i))
    check_tmp = columns_check(df_tmp)
    if check_tmp == 'DONE':
        return 'DONE'
    df_tmp=pd.DataFrame()
    for i, data in enumerate(dftt.iterrows()):
        index, row = data[0], data[1]
        df_tmp = df_tmp.append(row.shift(i))
    columns_check(df_tmp)
    check_tmp = columns_check(df_tmp)
    if check_tmp == 'DONE':
        return 'DONE'
    return 'The game is still on'
check = diagonal_check ()
print(check)
```

I made the code with functions, where different game over scenarios are checked.

you can call the both funktions like this:

```
check = columns_check(dftt)
```

or

```
ckeck = rows_check(dftt)
```

**EDIT** I edited the code above, so it returns a string 'DONE' when the game is over. I think this is what you want in you comment

** Edit** I created one more solution (look the code below) for your problem, which is more elegant and much faster.

```
X = 'x'
O = 'o'
def check_win (dftt):
    b = dftt.values
    diagonal1 = b.diagonal()
    diagonal2 = np.fliplr(b).diagonal()
    if 3 in (b==X).sum(axis=0) or 3 in (b==X).sum(axis=1) or (diagonal1==X).sum() == 3 or (diagonal2==X).sum() == 3:
            return(f"Game over, {X} wins")
    if 3 in (b==O).sum(axis=0) or 3 in (b==O).sum(axis=1) or (diagonal1==O).sum() == 3 or (diagonal2==O).sum() == 3:
            return(f"Game over, {O} wins")
    return 'The game is still on'




check_win (dftt)
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way i can change the game_status so that the loop ends and it doesnt just keep asking for input? @coco18